# Angular Binding Not Working/page load

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

**Question:** Why isn't my binding working?

**Explanation** I am taking some details from one component and loading them into another component. I can see that the values are being passed over  in my console, but I can not get them to bind in the view.

 I believe this is a time issue because of the order of events... User clicks "view more" from 1st component which calls a function that passes the values and navigates to the 2nd component... I know the values are being passed because I can see them in my console... From here I am lost, because I am trying to bind the values for the HTML to pick up...

**2nd question** Could this be a time issue? If I set the value in the ngOnInit it will show that value... if I set the value in the functions below, nothing display... I am thinking the page loads first with no values, and then the values load. Is there a way to solve this?


**Code**

```
//Function that is called from 1st Component//
patientPageLink(data){
    this.ppc.details(data)
    this.router.navigate(['/patient-page']);
}

//2nd Component//

ngOnInit() {
    this.patientName = "Test Name"  *THIS BINDS*
}

details(data){
    console.log("important", data)          *Values are there
    this.getPatientsDetails(data)
    this.patientName = data.first_name      *THIS DOESN'T BIND*
    console.log("check",this.patientName)   *Display's Name*
}


<!-- HTML -->

<table>
    <tr>
        <th class = "thead">First Name</th>
        <th class = "thead">Last Name</th>
        <th class = "thead">Date Of Birth</th>
    </tr>
    <tr >
        <th class = "thead">{{patientName}}</th>
        <th>Johnson</th>
        <th>04/04/1998</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: If you console log the data object, does first_name show up?

Comment: Also, what happens in getPatientDetails(data)?

Comment: How are you getting the reference to `this.ppc` in order to call `details`? I'm guessin it's a different copy to the one being displayed by the router

Comment: @nixkuroi no, the first console.log shows the whole array of data... and getPatientDetails is an API I used to try and get the data another way, but i still ended up in the same spot

Comment: @user184994 I'm not sure if I understand correctly, but it how is found to pass data from one component to another. Regardless, it may not be the best practice, but I am getting the value's in the 2nd component..

Comment: What I mean is, in the first component, how is `this.ppc` being set?

Comment: @user184994 it is a provider set in the app.module, and i import the 2nd component into the first component.. Kind of like how you would do an object, ie Hero id: number name:string

Comment: I think you'll find the instance that you're using is different to the instance that is being used by the router. You'd be far better off using a shared service for this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177517/discussion-between-mason-sb-and-user184994).

Answer (score 0):

you might want to be passing data through a service or as an input to a component. Is the first component a parent of the second component?

Here is the angular docs for component interaction:
https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#component-interaction

Comment: I am passing it through as a service... I am fairly new to Angular so I don't fully grasp what I practice. From my understanding however, yes the 2nd component is a child of the first. I can only be accessed through the first and it gets its values from the 1st.